# Get Month from django datetime model field

Tags: django

I am getting the following datetime from the model object:

```
m =  2021-02-14 15:57:16.222000+00:00
```

How can I get the month from this ?

m is :

m = i.delivery_month

When I try datetime.strptime(m[:10], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is already a `datetime` object, *not* a string, as is specified in by the error. You thus can obtain the month with:

```
m.month
```

or if you want to do date(time) formatting, you can work with:

```
m.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `m` is string:

```
from datetime import datetime
m =  '2021-02-14 15:57:16.222000+00:00'
dt = datetime.strptime(m, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(dt.month)
```